# How to generate random points that lie on a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, random

I have a shapefile with track lines and I need to generate random points from each 1 km of every line. There is a function in QGIS Random points but it offers to generate random points only inside a polygon. Any ideas for a specific plug-in or another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about from the processing toolbox where there's a tool called [Random points along line](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools.html?highlight=random%20points#random-points-along-line).

You can also set the minimum distance.

Comment: Thanks! I took a me a while to find out this processing algorithm is in Commander (not displaying in Toolbox) but I did and it works!.

Comment: @MiroslavKutal, you will need to change the simplified interface to advanced at the bottom of the toolbox. And your welcome!

Answer (score 2):

First off all you have to make sure that your Project and data CRS are in the Projected References. then go to:

Qgis > Processing > Toolbox > (type) Random points along line...
You´ll see it in **Vector creation tools** > right clik and execute...

[image]

Number points = If you put 1 you´ll only see one point,
Minimum distance = In meters (E.g. 1000).