# How to create random points on a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Can I generate random points on a shapefile created from a digitized road? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random points that lie on a line in qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201523/how-to-generate-random-points-that-lie-on-a-line-in-qgis)

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'Random points along line' from QGIS Processing Toolbox. At following image you can see an example for generating 10 random points with my line shapefile.

[image]